# SharePoint 2013 Search - Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: search, error

I have a problem with search on my SharePoint 2013 on-premis installation.

It just wont seem to work.

I have the Search Service Application setup and the System status advises that it has searched 5,302 items (running a continious crawl).

The 'find an item' search boxes within a list or document library are not working.

When I use the search box using my enterprise search centre box I receive this error:

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>
> Unknown Error
>
> Correlation ID: 0922f09c-9c16-703b-a4aa-9832d40de5b2

This seems to be the only part of SharePoint I cannot seem to get working, it all looks setup correctly as per documentation.

Any help with this would be amazing!

Thanks

Comment: Did you check logs for that correlation ID which you get when you receive error?

Comment: I have attached the log file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/szc2lexajchjoby/sp-error.txt?dl=0